# InternalOAuthError: failed to obtain request token passport-twitter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, passport-twitter

I followed the docs of passport-twitter
`

```
const TwitterStrategy = require("passport-twitter").Strategy
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ twitterId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

 app.get("/auth/twitter",
  passport.authenticate("twitter"));

app.get("/auth/twitter/callback", 
  passport.authenticate("twitter", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect("/logged");
  });
```

`but I ran with this error:`

```
InternalOAuthError: failed to obtain request token
    at /home/joseph/Desktop/vs_code/express/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth.js:196:36
    at /home/joseph/Desktop/vs_code/express/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:543:17
    at passBackControl (/home/joseph/Desktop/vs_code/express/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:397:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/joseph/Desktop/vs_code/express/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:409:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

`

What should I do??

I tried `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` and installing `npm i passport-twitter` again but it doesn't work. I am using npm: '9.1.2', node: '18.12.1', express 4.16.1